# Running shell Script via Crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, cron

So I've tried to run a shell script via crontab.

My Crontabs look like this:
`00 20 * * * $HOME/Bilder/Hintergründe/.background_skript/background_night.sh`

and my background_day.sh looks like this:

`#!/bin/bash
wallpaper="$HOME/Bilder/Hintergründe/appa_night.jpg"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark file:///"$wallpaper"`

I have already assigned the chmod rights with: `chmod +x background_night.sh`.

It also works fine if I run it directly with the shell.

And the grep CRON /var/log/syslog looks like this:

`May 25 15:07:01 sebs-thinkpad CRON[90433]: (seb) CMD (sh /home/seb/Bilder/Wallpaper/.background_skript/background_night.sh) May 25 15:08:01 sebs-thinkpad CRON[90472]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`

I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `> cron.log 2>&1` to have the cronjob write its output to a file, so that you could see the error messages it produces. (Some cron daemons automatically write the output to syslog when mail is not available; yours apparently doesn't.)

Most likely the problem is that 'gsettings set' works via D-Bus (the *session* bus, specifically, not the system bus) and usually requires either one of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` or `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variables to be present (depending on setup).

First of all, though:

- If your system has `systemctl --user` available, consider using its `.timer` units instead, as most likely your graphical desktop already forwards the necessary environment variables into your systemd per-user manager.
- If you don't want to deal with .timer and .service units, you could use `systemd-run` from crontab to start the script in the correct environment:

  ```
  00 20 * * * systemd-run --user ~/Bilder/Hintergründe/.background_skript/background_night.sh
  ```

If you want to do everything through cron:

1. Run `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in a terminal window and check what path is shown.
2. If the bus path was shown as `/run/user/XXX/bus`, its location is static – you can just put one of the following at the top of your cronjob (or, `export` them at the beginning of your script):

   ```
   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/XXX"
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/XXX/bus"
   ```

   (Usually XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is enough to cover D-Bus as well as various other components.)
3. If the bus path is shown as `/tmp/dbus-XXXXXXX`, it's dynamic – you need to store the value somewhere on every login:

   1. Edit `~/.xprofile` or `~/.xinitrc` (whichever applies) to store the environment in files:

      ```sh
      echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" > /tmp/dbus.env
      echo "$DISPLAY" > /tmp/display.env
      ```
   2. Edit your script to load the environment from files:

      ```sh
      export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(< /tmp/dbus.env)
      export DISPLAY=$(< /tmp/display.env)
      ```

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are run by root for all users. That means that some personal shortcuts are not appropriate:

- `$HOME` must be replaced by explicit path. `~/` also.
- The `$PATH` used by root is not your own customized `$PATH`. Use complete path for executables.
- Variables from your environment may not exist in root environment.