# Running shell Script via Systemd.timer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, timer

So I've essentially run into the same problem as in my other question: [Running shell Script via Crontab](https://superuser.com/questions/1785909/running-shell-script-via-crontab)

I will now run my shell script with systemd.timer but it is not working so far.

Here is my background.timer file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Changes between backgrounds

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10s
OnBootSec=10s
Unit=background.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And my background.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Changes between backgrounds

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/seb/Bilder/Wallpaper/.background_skript/skript.sh
```

And the file it should run:

```
#!/bin/bash
night="$HOME/Bilder/Wallpaper/appa_night.jpg"
day="$HOME/Bilder/Wallpaper/appa_day.jpg"

H=$(date +%H)

if [[ '13' < $H && $H < '20' ]]
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark file:///"$day"
else
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark file:///"$night"
fi
```

The bash file is also unable by myself from the terminal and my crontab had could also run it after the changes from my other question. Maby I have to do something similar in systemd?

Here is what my Crontab file looks like:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"


00 08 * * * systemd-run --user ~/Bilder/Wallpaper/.background_skript/skript.sh
00 20 * * * systemd-run --user ~/Bilder/Wallpaper/.background_skript/skript.sh
```

So far the systemd.service don't run the bash file at all nor change the background.

Comment: It seems like you're mixing two unrelated methods – either a .timer + .service *or* a systemd-run cronjob, not both. What happens if you do the `systemd-run...` manually from a shell, with the `--pty` option added? (Put a `set -x` at the top of your script, too.)

Comment: Please add (1) what `journalctl --user -u background.service` says and (2) how exactly you activated the timer (`systemctl --user enable --now background.timer`, I suppose, but just to double-check). Who owns the script? Who is allowed to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Dont call the script directly. It sounds to me like you are having permission issues.  instead of calling  `/path/to/script.sh` try infering bash with `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`

This could also be the problem for your cron issue